# How to configure application level settings in Websphere developer tool in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-7

I install WebSphere Developer tools for Eclipse and refer to my local WebSphere 7 installation. Then deploy a Spring application within an EAR project. However, when I deploy the EAR project into WebSphere server instance in Eclipse, I find no options/UI to assign external library or assign role/user mapping etc, just like what I can do in WebSphere console.

When log on WebSphere console I do see the project setting but cannot save the change.

So is there anyway to configure on the UI or I have to make every change in an WebSphere XML configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In Eclipse, I find no options/UI to assign external library or assign role/user mapping etc*
Yes, you have to do it via console.

*When log on WebSphere console I do see the project setting but cannot save the change.*
Thats the common problem. Open the Server configuration and **uncheck** `Minimize application files copied to the server`. Restart server, undeploy and redeploy application. You should be able to save mappings.

If this doesn't help (helps in most cases but not for some settings and I don't remember for which), then in the Publishing options, **switch** to `Run server with resources on Server`, this will work for sure, but deployment will be a bit longer. Of course restart and redeploy app.

You will see the missing `OK` buttons in the admin console then.

Comment: @Dreamer Did 'minimize' was enough or you had to switch?

Comment: Sorry I was off-line a bit for other errands. "Minimize application files copied to the server" does activate the OK/Apply button on WS console, but it report error like "Error: META-INF/maven/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/pom.xml" when try to assign user/role to current application(no error when switch class loader or assign share library), then "switch to Run server with resources on Server" resolve that error. So it has to use both options to make it work, move all control entirely back to Websphere console. The downside is it really eat a lot of memory.

Comment: @Dreamer Thanks for update. Strange, as I see no reason why it should touch pom file while saving mapping.

Comment: this is the exception regarding the pom error: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: META-INF/maven/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/pom.xml
Stack trace of nested exception:
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/maven/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/pom.xml

Comment: I guess it is may be that the deployment in eclipse server instance and websphere server may have duplicate jar/pom file, so check `Run server with resources on Server` may unify the resource location. Just 2 cents